# Как установить шаблонизатор Twig на ModX?

Tags: modx, twig, шаблонизаторы

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример, как установить шаблонизатор Twig на ModX.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно уделить две секунды на поиск в гугле чтобы найти ссылку http://community.modx-cms.ru/blog/dev/10283.html описывающую всё что нужно для этого.